# how to get callable column name in jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, callable-statement

As we all know, if we execute a sql for query, we can use `rs.getMetaData()` to get the result metadata. We use it to get the resultset column.

But if I use a callable, I want to get the column for the OUT Mode column name. How can i get it?

Comment: Are you using `registerOutParameter` method to retrieve result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method:

> java.sql.DatabaseMetaData.getColumns(String catalog, String
>   schemaPattern, String tableNamePattern, String columnNamePattern)
>
> Each column description has the following columns:
>   Each column description has the following columns:

```
   1. TABLE_CAT String => table catalog (may be null)
   2. TABLE_SCHEM String => table schema (may be null)
   3. TABLE_NAME String => table name
   4. COLUMN_NAME String => column name
   5. DATA_TYPE int => SQL type from java.sql.Types
   6. TYPE_NAME String => Data source dependent type name, for a UDT the type name is fully qualified
   7. COLUMN_SIZE int => column size.
   8. BUFFER_LENGTH is not used.
   9. DECIMAL_DIGITS int => the number of fractional digits. Null is returned for data types where DECIMAL_DIGITS is not applicable.
  10. NUM_PREC_RADIX int => Radix (typically either 10 or 2)
  11. NULLABLE int => is NULL allowed.
          * columnNoNulls - might not allow NULL values
          * columnNullable - definitely allows NULL values
          * columnNullableUnknown - nullability unknown 
  12. REMARKS String => comment describing column (may be null)
  13. COLUMN_DEF String => default value for the column, which should be interpreted as a string when the value is enclosed in single quotes (may be null)
  14. SQL_DATA_TYPE int => unused
  15. SQL_DATETIME_SUB int => unused
  16. CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH int => for char types the maximum number of bytes in the column
  17. ORDINAL_POSITION int => index of column in table (starting at 1)
  18. IS_NULLABLE String => ISO rules are used to determine the nullability for a column.
          * YES --- if the parameter can include NULLs
          * NO --- if the parameter cannot include NULLs
          * empty string --- if the nullability for the parameter is unknown 
  19. SCOPE_CATLOG String => catalog of table that is the scope of a reference attribute (null if DATA_TYPE isn't REF)
  20. SCOPE_SCHEMA String => schema of table that is the scope of a reference attribute (null if the DATA_TYPE isn't REF)
  21. SCOPE_TABLE String => table name that this the scope of a reference attribure (null if the DATA_TYPE isn't REF)
  22. SOURCE_DATA_TYPE short => source type of a distinct type or user-generated Ref type, SQL type from java.sql.Types (null if DATA_TYPE isn't DISTINCT or user-generated REF)
  23. IS_AUTOINCREMENT String => Indicates whether this column is auto incremented
          * YES --- if the column is auto incremented
          * NO --- if the column is not auto incremented
          * empty string --- if it cannot be determined whether the column is auto incremented parameter is unknown
```

A simple implementation:

```
ResultSet columns = dbmd.getColumns(null, null, tableName, null);
final List<String> columnList = new ArrayList<String>();
while (columns.next())
{
     columnList.add(columns.getString(4));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure its tableName and not Stored Proc Name?